# Convert / cast string to numeric with Dutch locale

Tags: postgresql, casting, type-conversion

I have a string like `12,3` in my PostgreSQL database, which I want to cast / convert to a numeric or double type. If I would have the English decimal point, I could simply do `'12.3'::numeric(10,2)`.

I can of course replace the comma with `REPLACE` but that feels 'hacky', as this is a locale problem, not a string processing problem.

Is there something like a "cast with locale" option in PostgreSQL (I am using version 10.10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `lc_numeric` variable?

(US locale)

```
SET lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8';
SELECT to_number('12,3','99G999D9S');

 to_number 
-----------
       123
```

(German locale)

```
SET lc_numeric = 'de_DE.UTF-8';
SELECT to_number('12,3','99G999D9S');

 to_number 
-----------
      12.3
```

Further reading: [`to_number`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) formatting function

Comment: This works yes, although it doesn't process the thousands separator correctly in my case.

Comment: @BartFriederichs did you take a look at `to_number`'s documentation? It most certainly has a format that suits your strings, e.g. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_number/